# How to read binary blob from Firebird to byte[] with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, firebird

I have very poor knowledge of C#, but I need to write code, that read binary blob to `byte[]`.

I wrote this code:

```
byte[] userBlob;

myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT id, userblob FROM USERS";
myCommand.Connection = myFBConnection;
myCommand.Transaction = myTransaction;

FbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

try
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
        userBlob = // what I should to do here??
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Can't read data from DB");
}
```

But what I should place here? As I understood I need use streams, but I can't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string);
```

So, in your case;

```
userBlob = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.GetString(0));
```

However, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with your code as you are pulling back all users and then creating the blob over and over.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the game; I hope this is on point.

I assuming you're using the Firebird .NET provider, which is a C# implementation that does not ride on top of the native `fbclient.dll`.  Unfortunately, it does not provide a streaming interface to BLOBs, which would allow for reading potentially huge data in chunks without blowing out memory.

Instead, you use the `FbDataReader.GetBytes()` method to read the data, and it all has to fit in memory. `GetBytes` takes a user-provided buffer and stuffs the BLOB data in the position referenced, and it returns the number of bytes it actually copied (which could be less than the full size).

Passing a `null` buffer to `GetBytes` returns you the full size of the BLOB (but no data!) so you can reallocate as needed.

Here we assume you have an INT for field #0 (not interesting) and the BLOB for #1, and this naive implementation should take care of it:

```
// temp buffer for all BLOBs, reallocated as needed
byte [] blobbuffer = new byte[512];

while (reader.Read())
{
    int id = reader.GetInt32(0);  // read first field

    // get bytes required for this BLOB
    long n = reader.GetBytes(
                 i: 1,  // field number
                 dataIndex: 0,
                 buffer: null,    // no buffer = size check only
                 bufferIndex: 0,
                 length: 0);

    // extend buffer if needed
    if (n > blobbuffer.Length)
        blobbuffer = new byte[n];

    // read again into nominally "big enough" buffer
    n = reader.GetBytes(1, 0, blobbuffer, 0, blobbuffer.Length);

    // Now: <n> bytes of <blobbuffer> has your data. Go at it.
}
```

It's possible to optimize this somewhat, but the Firebird .NET provider really needs a streaming BLOB interface like the native fbclient.dll offers.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. I have read a 105,600 bytes blob in a blink of an eye.